# Azure Logic App "When a HTTP request is received" Connector multiple relative paths

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible to have multiple endpoint to one Logic App. 
eg:

```
https://azure-url/invoke/customers/all
https://azure-url/invoke/customers/{specific_id}
https://azure-url/invoke/customers/{specific_id}/brand/all
https://azure-url/invoke/customers/{specific_id}/brand/{brand_id}
```

How to achieve this using single/multiple HTTP Receiver in one Logic App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a workaround for my problem, we cannot have multiple path param for a one Logic App, but we can use API Management top on Logic App.
In the APIM,

1. Need to create different operations for each PATH Params[Operation with TWO Path param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4hvt.png)[Operation with ONE path param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lu38.png)[Operation with THREE path param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkV8P.png)
2. Add APIM path param values as a policy to the backend

   `<set-query-parameter name="vendor_id" exists-action="override">`  
      `<value>@(context.Request.MatchedParameters["vendor_id"])</value>`
   `</set-query-parameter>` 

   `<set-query-parameter name="brand_id" exists-action="override">`
   `<value />`
   `</set-query-parameter>`
   `<set-query-parameter name="family_id" exists-action="override">`
   `<value />`
   `</set-query-parameter>`

in the above code, we need to pass an empty string if path param doesn't have values.

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, you can use "API Management" in azure. Please refer to the steps below:

**1.** Create a API Management by following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/get-started-create-service-instance).

**2.** Go to your API Management and add a api from the logic app.
[image]

**3.** Choose your logic app in it, then create.
[image]

**4.** We can see the "Frontend" of it and click the pencil to edit it.
[image]

**5.** Edit the "URL" as what you want, save.
[image]

**6.** You can get the request url under the "Test" tab.
[image]

**7.** After that, you can add other three apis by the same steps above, just edit the "URL" of "Frontend" with what you want. If you want to input {specific_id}, just edit the "URL" as below:

```
/manual/paths/invoke/customers/{specific_id}
/manual/paths/invoke/customers/{specific_id}/brand/all
/manual/paths/invoke/customers/{specific_id}/brand/{brand_id}
```

Hope it helps~

Comment: This is on Azure API Management, but I'm looking for a solution in Logic App. Basically, Logic App HTTP Request should supply multiple URL Path Params.

Comment: @Siva Sorry, I'm afraid that we can't implement this requirement just in logic app http request.

Comment: Yes, I end up using Logic app and API Management. Thanks for your comments.